# Redirect back with errors

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-4

I have a controller:

**controller/streets_controller.rb**

```
class StreetsController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_street, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]

  def show
    @house = @street.houses.build
  end

  .......
```

And a view for that `show` action. There I also display a form to create new street houses:

**views/streets/show.html.erb**

```
<h1>Street</h1>
<p>@street.name</p>

<%= render '/houses/form', house: @house %>
```

When somebody submits the `houses/form` the request goes to the **houses_controller.rb**

```
class HousesController < ApplicationController

  def create
    @house = House.new(house_params)

    respond_to do |format|
      if @house.save
        format.html { redirect_back(fallback_location: streets_path) }
        format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @house }
      else
        format.html { redirect_back(fallback_location: streets_path) }
        format.json { render json: @house.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end
```

So far it works that when somebody inserts correct `house_params` it redirects back and creates the house **correctly**

But when somebody inserts wrong `house_params` it redirects_back but it doesn't show the house errors in the form, it shows the form for a new house `@house = @street.houses.build`

**How can I redirect to the `StreetsController` with the `@house` object, so that the errors are shown and also the house form is filled?**

**Thanks**

Comment: What are the possible pages that a user could be redirected back to?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Generally when there is an error in the create action, you would render the "new" view instead of redirecting back. In your case, you could try redirecting to the streets show path, and passing the `@house` attributes as query params. Then in `StreetsController#show`, pass the house params as an argument to `build`.